# django1.8 api - how to authenticate with a key

Tags: django

I want to allow the django users to use a key in the api urls for authentication.
I do not have OAUTH set up yet so I guess the key could be a sesion key or a digest key.
I'm having 2 problems.
I've tried sending this request:

```
http://192.166.166.11:8000/api?task=search&term=115&csrf_token=s69WAIZqlCTur1XZQr72QhCc7fzqaRtM
```

First of all, I've tried using the **csrf_token** but it does not work.
It takes me to the login page.
Secondly, I do not know how to retrieve csrf_token of other users (the admin is trying to get their csrf_tokens).

My attempt:

```
x = User.objects.get(username='someone')
x.get_session_auth_hash()
```

gives me the user's authentication hash but it is a different value.

Can someone please guide me get these two problems sorted out?

Comment: What? Why do you think you need other users' CSRF token, or even think a CSRF token is allocated to a particular user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django doesn't provide API Keys out of the box.
Use API providers such as [Tastypie](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to have this feature

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a token-based authentication. You already mentioned OAUTH as one option, and I strongly recommend using one of the existing implementations like [django-oauth-toolkit](http://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/tutorial_01.html). However, you can also create your own quick solution to create a token-based authentication.

**Disclaimer: This is for demo purposes only. Do not copy it in any existing project. It will make your application vulnerable.**

First, we create an additional model handling the authentication tokens:

*/auth_tokens/models.py*

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

import string, random

def random_string(length = 64, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(length))

class AuthToken(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    token = models.CharField(max_length=64, default=random_string)
```

*/auth_tokens/middleware.py*

```
from auth_tokens.models import AuthToken

class AuthTokenMiddleware:
    def process_request(self, request): 
        token = request.GET.get('auth', None)
        if not token: 
            return
        token = AuthToken.objects.get(token=token)
        request.user = token.user
        return request
```

Including the middleware into your `settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` should enable you to add `?token=<token>` to your URL to login your users.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using token authentication:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/

so I'd like to share the workflow.

First, you need to do the set up. In settings.py, modify INSTALLED_APPS and add REST_FRAMEWORK as in documentation.
Then you need to run `python manage.py syncdb` because it needs to add some tables.
Then, you need to add some urls to urls.py to route the api.
You can create and retrieve tokens using this code:

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
token = Token.objects.create(user=User.objects.get(username='john'))
print token.key
```

Lastly, you'll have to modify your view which depends on whether you're using a function based or class based view.
Here is a function based view I used:

```
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.decorators import authentication_classes, permission_classes
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@authentication_classes((TokenAuthentication,))
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
@login_required
def mybooks(request):
    entries = Book.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'mybooks.html', {'entries': entries})
```

Lastly, to test it out:

```
import requests
token = '243124c52f7583e320d043c4395bd99f63344035'
headers = {'Authorization' : 'Token {}'.format(token)}
page = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/mybooks/', headers=headers)
print page.content
```

Note that in my case I do not need define plain serialization since I have an advanced custom serialization and that is not the topic here.